# Oracle Baseline not being used

Tags: oracle11g

I have a SQL_ID (1234567890abc) and I'm trying to bind the execution of the query to a baseline. So I'm doing the following:

```sql
var v_num number;
exec :v_num:=dbms_spm.load_plans_from_cursor_cache(sql_id =>'1234567890abc',plan_hash_value => 1122334455);
```

(let's suppose 1122334455 is the plan hash for the sql_id "1234567890abc." I think it's not mandatory to set this value, but I do it anyway)

So the baseline is added. I check it using

```sql
select * from dba_sql_plan_baselines;
```

But if I execute the query two or three times again, the execution plan does not show in the notes that the baseline is now in use, and the column sql_plan_baseline for the row with sql_id = '1234567890abc' in the table v$sqlarea is null. The number of executions is incremented.

I tried to purge the sql_id from the shared pool using:

```sql
select address, hash_value from v$sqlarea where sql_id='1234567890abc';
execute sys.dbms_shared_pool.purge('0000000000ABCDEF,0987654321','Z');
```

But if I send the query again, a new row is created in v$sqlarea and once again the column sql_plan_baseline of the table v$sqlarea is null.

I tried to gather all schema stats (using no_invalidate => false), and even restarting the database but nothing changes. I also tried to mark the baseline as fixed, but it was useless.

the Oracle version is 11.2.0.1.0, the parameter optimizer_capture_sql_plan_baselines is set to false and optimizer_use_sql_plan_baselines is set to true

What am I doing wrong? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally, I've found out that baselines are available in the Enterprise Edition, and I'm using a Standard one.

https://blogs.oracle.com/optimizer/does-the-use-of-sql-plan-management-and-the-dbmsspm-database-package-require-a-tuning-or-diagnostic-pack-license